# Strategy for sending delayed pushes

Tags: push-notification, architecture, software-design

I have application that should notify user based on some interval pattern like:

```
Event
    > Pushes
            Pattern: Immediately - 3 day - 7 day - 12 day
```

If user made action for event pushes should stops for this event. It is possible to have multiple same type events that should send push when event occurred.
Also I do not want to bother user for example when the one have 5 events to send x5 more pushes, but reduce by taking together pushes that should happens next day (or some other interval) by sending one push for example 'reminder: you have 5 events'.

So now I decide this kind of solution, when event occurred, insert into db all pushes for event that should be send later with datetime for send. If user take action, pushes marks as redundant for this event. And before sending analyze interval for example take all pushes for next 24hour, send one and mark all others as already sent.

Is it ok, or maybe exists better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I have experience building same application with you. What I'm I doing is :

> CMS -> redis -> worker

- **CMS**, are used for creating push notification content, including the time when that content should be sent
- **Redis**, are used for storing the delayed jobs data
- **Worker**, php application that  pulling delayed jobs data from Redis. I use Laravel on here, I take advantage from [Laravel queue delayed dispatching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#delayed-dispatching).

Previously I have try use database and message broker [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) as queue driver. Why I'm switch to redis ? First, when I using database, is too costly, due the traffic of my queue data is very huge. Then when I use SQS, it's better than database, but SQS cannot hold delayed data with weeks age. So my last choice is Redis. Of course we can use another serivce such as [Rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com).